# How to Convert mysql functions to modern PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a login system which I have been using with mysql functions like real_escape_strings  and  more . but now  I am trying to convert it to PDO since its more modern than mysql  functions . the problem is now it does not work with PDO .below is my code please tell me what i mght be doing wrong .

```
<?php
try {
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8','root','');

} catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Connection failed'.$e->getMessage();
}

?>
<?php 
$is_ajax = $_POST['is_ajax'];
    if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)

    {
$username =(isset($_POST['username']))? trim($_POST['username']): '';
$Password=(isset($_POST['Password']))? $_POST['Password'] : '';
$redirect=(isset($_REQUEST['redirect']))? $_REQUEST['redirect'] :
'view.php';
$query ='SELECT username FROM tish_user WHERE '.
'username="'.($username,$con).'" AND ' .
   'Password = md5("'.($Password,$con).'")';
  $result = $con->prepare($query); 
   $result->execute();
        if(count($result)>0)
        {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
            echo "success"; 
        }
        else {
//set these explicitly just to make sure 

}
    }

?>
```

Comment: `($username,$con)` - what is this?

Comment: @Your Common Sense  Yo you a great man that was the only problem . so u fixed thanks 100% . every problem I get You manage to solve it thanks once again

Comment: Please, learn about ***the modern way*** to create queries: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: @YourCommonSense now how can I escape strings in pdo ?

Comment: @humphrey By using the modern way, i.e. prepared statements: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: @deceze  great I will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after removing all useless code

```
<?php
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8','root','');

if(!empty($_POST['is_ajax']))
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM tish_user WHERE username=? AND Password = md5(?)';
    $stm = $con->prepare($sql); 
    $stm->execute(array($_POST['username'],$_POST['Password']));
    if($row = $stm->fetch())
    {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    }
}
?>
```

you need to check letter case too. capital 'Password' looks suspicious. Better choose one standard (all lowercase) and follow it everywhere

Here is my answer on the [How prepared statements can protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587) question explaining how it works

Comment: Yes this great but I would like to ask does this code escapes Strings ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ='SELECT username FROM tish_user WHERE username=? AND Password = md5(?) )';
$result = $con->prepare($query); 
$result->execute(array($username, $password));
```

This will automatically escape strings for you.